# How I Change Complete Url In asp.net with help of url rewriting?

Tags: asp.net

How I Change Complete Url In asp.net with help of url rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own HttpModule (class that derives from IHttpModule interface) and in OnBeginRequest use method RewritePath:

```
HttpContext.RewritePath("Default.aspx?id=1", false);
```

but you have to little configure IIS. If you have IIS less than 7 you muss map all requests to aspnet_isapi.dll

in vesion 7 you add only attribute runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to web.config to system.webServer > modules element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [IIS7 URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/).